# R: given a matrix of 0 and 1s create matrix showing repetition between columns in rows

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

## Setting

The title isn't very informative, so I'm open to editing it. Suppose I have the following data frame

```
m <- matrix(c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), nrow=3, ncol=4, 
            dimnames = list(c("row1", "row2", "row3"), c("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4")))
df <- data.frame(m)
```

It looks like this

```
     col1 col2 col3 col4
row1    1    0    1    0
row2    0    1    0    0
row3    1    0    1    1
```

## What I want to do

I want to obtain something similar to this (the diagonal can either have all `0`s or all `1`s, I don't care).

```
       col1  col2  col3  col4
col1      0     0     2     1
col2      0     0     0     0
col3      2     0     0     1
col4      1     0     1     0
```

Basically if any two columns have a `1` on the same row (for instance `col1` and `col3` both have a `1` on `row1` and `row3`) then we add +1 to the corresponding entry in the matrix above. Basically the final matrix counts the number of times that each column has `1`s on the same row as other columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option is `crossprod` after converting to `matrix` and then change the `diag`onal elements to 0

```
`diag<-`(crossprod(as.matrix(df)), 0)
#     col1 col2 col3 col4
#col1    0    0    2    1
#col2    0    0    0    0
#col3    2    0    0    1
#col4    1    0    1    0
```

Comment: Can you please explain this piece of code? I'm quite lost. I thought `crossprod` computed  `t(m) %*% m`

Comment: I can't believe this piece of code works! My current function was about 30 lines long and it included `outer`, loops and lots of other stuff..

Comment: @Euler_Salter If you check `?crossprod`, 'y' can be NULL `crossprod(x, y = NULL)`

Comment: `crossprod(x, y=NULL)` should be equivalent to `t(x) %*% x` right?

Comment: also what is `'diag<-'` doing?

Comment: It would be similar to `t(df) %*% as.matrix(df)`, but would be more efficient

Comment: @Euler_Salter. I could have done the assignment in two steps, i.e. `out <- crossprod(as.matrix(df)); diag(out) <- 0`

Comment: I'm baffled as to how quickly you came up with a solution. What was your thought process?

Comment: @Euler_Salter There is no single line answer for your question :-)